# MS DTC errors on SQL Server 2008 R2 but not SQL Server 2000 running on difference instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, msdtc

I am receiving errors when I try to run a distributed query against different SQL Server 2008 R2. At first I thought this might be cause the servers have been set up on a VM using a clone but after I discovered that I could run this query on SQL Server 2000 but it fails on a SQL Server 2008 R2 on the same server I am beginning to think that there is something I am just missing.

It does run without any issues on another developers network but it isn't running VMs

Steps I have done so far:

1. Totally uninstalled MS-DTC, rebooted and installed MS-DTC and another reboot.
2. Ran Dtcping - no errors
3. Checked to make sure there are no duplicate SIDs
4. Asked my non geek wife. She changed the subject to shopping
5. Rechecked the link servers - everything checks out.
6. Ran profiler on the transaction - no information given.
7. Checked the MS-DTC on production boxes to look for anything I might have missed. Also checked out from `sp_configure` from production boxes to look for anything that I might have missed.
8. uninstalled/reinstalled MSDTC just in case.
9. Made sure that the security on DTC isn't stopping me from doing anything.
10. Firewalls are off on every server I had played with.
11. Got caught googling MSDTC on my phone while having lunch with my wife.
12. Updated my servers for with any missing patches.
13. Talked to my dog about it. At least he listen but didn't have any answers.
14. Picked up everything and tried it on a different server. No change.
15. Read the logs from MSDTC to find out that the parent node is the one asking for the abort request

Comment: long story short, what's error?

Comment: abort request issued to transaction child node or parent node. The actual error message is deep in the MSDTC logs that need to be translated using tracefmt

Comment: Another strange development. I attempted to run subinacl to adjust the permission levels - access denied even running as administrator on the server

Answer (score 1):

We have run into issues when servers were re-named and we had to set the DTC security properties to "No Authentication Required" on all servers involved in the transaction. This is not a best practice but works for internal network only servers. Directions to the DTC security settings can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731495.aspx